# Tastypie: Add meta codes to dispatch_list

Tags: python, django, api, rest, tastypie

How can I add custom fields (in this case, meta codes) to a `dispatch_list` in Tastypie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new field to the resource and dehydrate it with dehydrate_field_name().

Comment: I'm just trying to add a meta code, eg 200, 400, 401 etc into the meta{} for checking on my iOS app when I call the API.

Comment: You can override get_list() and add your code. Something like this: to_be_serialized['meta']['status_code'] = status_code

Answer (score 5):

a better approach IMHO would be to use the function made to override/add fields to the data before making the response:

```
    def alter_list_data_to_serialize(self, request, data):
        data['meta']['current_time'] = datetime.strftime(datetime.utcnow(), "%Y/%m/%d") 
        return data
```